# Django Login form issue

Tags: django, authentication, django-forms

Views.py

```
def Tourist_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Tourist_login_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']


            user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
            print(user)

            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                messages.success(request,'logged in')
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.error(request,"Invalid login credentials!")
                return redirect('touristlogin')
        else:
            return redirect('touirstlogin')
    else:
        form = Tourist_login_form()
        return render(request,'accounts/tourist_login.html',{'form':form})
```

In the above code , authenticate function returns none value. But if I'm passing input in form through superuser credentials then it is working fine. I'm not able why is it not taking the username and password passed by the user and only taking superuser username and password.

Comment: would you please share the html code? also try to print username and password before authenticate()

Comment: Hi Monish! I tried printing both username and password it is returning  both the  values , but authenticate is not working still

Comment: Have you tried the below code i gave in answer?

Comment: You can share the error if you're still facing it.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try using this way:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import auth
user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
   auth.login(request, user)
   messages.success(request,'logged in')
   return redirect('home')
```